# Google maps not displaying markers on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with my google map, its not displaying any markers at all. The data for the markers comes from wordpress post and custom fields.

I did a console log for `var locations` and the data is passed to this point. Also did a console log for `var j` and I'm getting there `undefined`.

What could be the problem that the markers are not displayed?

```
    <?php 
     $args = array('post_type'=> 'investments'); $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $investmentsData[$row]['meta'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'investments_location_details', true );
        $investmentsData[$row]['investment'] = [
          'id' => get_the_id(),
          'title' => get_the_title(),
        ];

          foreach ($investmentsData as $key => $value) {
            $investment = $value['tabs'];
            $meta = $value['meta'];
          }

          wp_localize_script('jquery-core', 'investmentsData', $investmentsData);

          ?>
          <div id="map"></div>

          <script type="text/javascript">
             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                 zoom: 11,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.233985, 16.8903183),
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             });
             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
             var marker, i;
             var locations = <?php echo json_encode($investmentsData) ?>;
             var j = locations.length;

             function initMap() {
                 for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: new google.maps.LatLng(investmentsData[i].lat, investmentsData[i].lng),
                       map: map,
                    });

                     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                         return function() {
                             infowindow.setContent(investmentsData[i].title);
                             infowindow.open(map, marker);
                         }
                     })(marker, i));
                 }
             };
         </script>

      <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wp_reset_query();
      ?>
```

**UPDATE**

The consol log for var locations is giving an object with

```
 investment: {id: 192, title: "Post title"}
 meta: {lat: "54.3765137", lng: "18.5707837"}
```

When I'm doing a console log of `investmentsData[i].lat` I get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: investmentsData is not defined` and for `locations[i].lat` I get this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`

I'm inducing the API like this `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5rsZHHAmzP_pOuHGKEUtarn2QideIyUM"></script>`

**Update from comment on answer**

The locations variable is an object:

```
var locations = {"":{"meta":{"lat":"54.2427318","lng":"16.8870907"},"investment":{"id":386,"title":"Termoizolacja obiekt\u00f3w u\u017cyteczno\u015bci publicznej na terenie..."}}};
```

Comment: Probably you need to replace `investmentsData[i]` by `locations[i]` as you don't define this `investmentsData` Javascript variable.

Comment: How are you calling the `initMap` function?

Comment: only as shown in the code

Comment: So you are not calling this function anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. With appropriate function calls and demo data.

```js
function initMap() {

  var locations = [{
      investment: {
        id: 192,
        title: "Post title 1"
      },
      meta: {
        lat: "54.3765137",
        lng: "18.5707837"
      }
    },
    {
      investment: {
        id: 193,
        title: "Post title 2"
      },
      meta: {
        lat: "54",
        lng: "18"
      }
    }
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.233985, 16.8903183),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;

  var j = locations.length;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].meta.lat, locations[i].meta.lng),
      map: map,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i].investment.title);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: @Dariusz the way to say thanks here is by up-voting or accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your code:

1. `lat` and `lng` are properties of the `locations[i].meta` object
2. `title` is a property of the `locations[i].investment` object
3. you aren't calling `initMap`
4. your map's center and zoom are set such that you can't see the marker.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9m4v53px/3/)

**update**

per the information on your live page, `locations` is an object, not an array:

```
var locations = {"":{"meta":{"lat":"54.2427318","lng":"16.8870907"},"investment":{"id":386,"title":"Termoizolacja obiekt\u00f3w u\u017cyteczno\u015bci publicznej na terenie Gminy K\u0119pice"}}};
```

process that by using:

```
for (var obj in locations) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[obj].meta.lat, locations[obj].meta.lng),
    map: map,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[obj].investment.title);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9m4v53px/5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.233985, 16.8903183),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var locations = {
      "": {
        "meta": {
          "lat": "54.2427318",
          "lng": "16.8870907"
        },
        "investment": {
          "id": 386,
          "title": "Termoizolacja obiekt\u00f3w u\u017cyteczno\u015bci publicznej na terenie Gminy K\u0119pice"
        }
      }
    };

    for (var obj in locations) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[obj].meta.lat, locations[obj].meta.lng),
        map: map,
      });
      console.log("marker position:" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[obj].investment.title);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  };
  initMap();
</script>
```

Comment: When I use your locations everything works fine. When I enter `<?php echo json_encode($investmentsData) ?>`  to `var locations` then I don't have any markers. But I see all the data on consol.log. What could be the problem?

Comment: I asked several times for a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  My guess is that the information in your question isn't enough to reproduce your problem.  If you view source on your page, what is being sent to the browser for this line: `var locations = <?php echo json_encode($investmentsData) ?>;`?

Comment: This is what I was looking for: `var locations = {"":{"meta":{"lat":"54.2427318","lng":"16.8870907"},"investment":{"id":386,"title":"Termoizolacja obiekt\u00f3w u\u017cyteczno\u015bci publicznej na terenie Gminy K\u0119pice"}}};`

Comment: updated the code snippet in the answer to handle that.

Comment: Thank you for your update. One more thing when I change the `var locations` from your snippet to `<?php echo json_encode($investmentsData) ?>;` then the markers are gone

Comment: Look at the error in the console (has nothing to do with the maps code)

Comment: And you have multiple `initMap` functions (all targeting the same `<div>`).  That won't work.  Currently the last one run is winning and that marker is at the North Pole (off the map, `marker position:90,116.2`)